# Is there any Swift's enum-with-associated-properties equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, properties

In Swift, we can do this for enums:

```
enum InputType {
    case unknown
    case data(Data)
    case profile(id: String, name: String, dateOfBirth: Date)
    case photos([Image])
}
```

And we can use it like so:

```
public func setup(basedOn inputType: InputType) throws {
    switch inputType {
        case let .data(dataInput): dataSetup(dataInput)
        case let .profile(id, name, dateOfBirth): profileSetup(id: id, name: name, dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth)
        case let .photos(photoImages): imagesSetup(photoImages)
        case .unknown: throw UnknownDataTypeError()
    }
}
```

Is there anything that can provide the same functionality with this in C#? Or perhaps a workaround to get a similar result? I was thinking of using a struct like this:

```
enum InputType {
    Unknown,
    Data,
    Profile,
    Photos
}

struct InputTypeWithProperty 
{
    public InputType inputType;
    public Object property; // Can be Data / Profile / Images class. Will need to be casted when consumed.
}
```

But that is too dirty for me to handle and I don't really like it. So, if anyone has any suggestion, can you tell me about it?

Thank you.

Comment: No, although such Discriminated Unions are a commonly-requested feature. The normal workaround is to use a class hierarchy

Comment: @canton7 I see. Can you give me some example? I can't think of any except by using a BaseClass with nothing on it and then I just cast it based on the `inputType` value (eg. if (inputType == InputType.Data) { Data data = (Data)property; dataSetup(data);  }). Which is essentially the same as using Object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use interfaces and record classes/structs to represent the enum with associated values. e.g.

```
public interface IInputType {}
public record Data(byte[] Bytes): IInputType;
public record Profile(string Id, string Name, string DateOfBirth): IInputType;
public record Photos(List<Bitmap> Images): IInputType;
```

Note that I omitted the "unknown" case, because unlike an enum with associated values, this hierarchy is extendible. Anyone can add a new type that implements `IInputType`, so in this design, anything that isn't `Data`, `Profile`, or `Photos` is "unknown". You could prevent people from adding their own input types to an extent by changing the interface to an abstract record and making the constructor internal, but the compiler still doesn't know that, and it won't correctly determine the exhaustiveness of your switch statements like Swift does.

Here's an example of how to read an `IInputType` using [recursive pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns) in a switch statement:

```
switch (inputType) {
    case Data { Bytes: var bytes }: 
        Console.WriteLine(bytes);
        break;
    case Profile { Id: var id, Name: var name, DateOfBirth: var dob }: 
        Console.WriteLine($"{id} {name} {dob}");
        break;
    case Photos { Images: var images }: 
        Console.WriteLine(images);
        break;
    default:
        throw new UnknownDataTypeException();
};
```

Notice how the "associated values" in each case are captured using `var`.

If you can use a switch expression instead, it could be much more concise:

```
var result = inputType switch {
    Data { Bytes: var bytes } => someResult
    Profile { Id: var id, Name: var name, DateOfBirth: var dob } => someOtherResult
    Photos { Images: var images } => yetAnotherResult
    - => throw new UnknownDataTypeException()
};
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. I think I will do it like this. However due to an old mandatory plugin that is not compatible (and not being maintained for now), I will be using an old version of C# where there is no `record`. I think I will use a regular class instead. Thanks again.